# Javascript/jquery: Remove parent of class and keep it's child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to remove a parent of a child with specific classname with javascript/jquery. It's a span wrapper which i'd like to remove. I only know the class (or id) of the child to work with.

How can i do that?

So this:

```
<span>
  <input class="removespan" type="text">
</span>
```

Needs to be this:

```
<input class="removespan" type="text">
```

Comment: It's well worth your time to read through the jQuery API from beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, two tops, and it pays you that time back very quickly. :-)

Comment: Learning javascript/jquery is on my schedule, but i kinda needed this codesnippet now. Normally i would have searched for other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazingly, jQuery has a method for doing *exactly* that: [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$(".removespan").unwrap();
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".removespan").unwrap();
}, 1000);
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 8px">
The span has a green border. The span is removed after a second:
</div>
<div>
<span>
  <input class="removespan" type="text">
</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Got it working on my testsite. Thanks. Too bad it's not working on my project site yet. Have to figure out why. Something is blocking it.